# C++ class/object function usage query

Tags: c++, class, function, object, parameters

I have a class with defined functions that need to be passed as parameters.
I want to setup a new instance of this class (with parameters) as an object(?).

Getting stuck with the syntax.

```
class classname{
void classfunction1(int, int);
void classfunction2(int, int);
};

void classname::classfunction1 (int a, int b)
{ // function }

void classname::classfunction2 (int a, int b)
{ // function uses classfunction1 }
```

I want to define the params for classfunction1, which will be used in classfunction 2 and assign an object(?), of that type so that intellisense will pick it up.

Pseudo:

```
int main(){
classname(20, 20) object;
object.classfunction2(50, 50);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you're trying to achieve, your pseudo-code doesn't really make any sense, sorry. Are you looking for how to write a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main is a bit wonky at the minute.

```
int main(){
    classname(20, 20) object; // You are incorrectly calling a constructor which does not exist
    object.classfunction2(50, 50); // more like correct behavior.
}
```

The class you have defined does not have any member variables, so it does not `store` any data. It only holds two functions. So this means that you can use the "default constructor" that the compiler defines for every class ( you can provide your own if you wish ).

```
int main(){
    classname object; // Call the default constructor
    object.classfunction1(10, 20); // Call the functions you want.
    object.classfunction2(50, 50); 
}
```

If you wanted to provide a constructor you should do something like:

```
class classname{
  public:
    classname(int variable1, int variable2): 
            member1(variable1), member2(variable2){}; //note that there is no return type
    void classfunction1(); //because instead of taking parameters it uses member1 & 2
    void classfunction2(int, int);

  private: 
    int member1;
    int member2;
};
```

You main would then look like:

```
int main(){
    classname object(10, 20); // Call the default constructor. Note that the (10, 20) is AFTER "object".
    object.classfunction1();  // Call the function... it will use 10 and 20.
    object.classfunction2(50, 50); //This function will use 50, 50 and then call classfunction1 which will use 10 and 20.
}
```

A couple of things to note: The way you attempted to call the first constructor was wrong, you need the parameters after the variable name.
See comments below for another thing to watch out for.

Comment: `classname(20, 20) object;` does not call a constructor, in fact it means nothing in the language (it is illegal). `classname object();` does not call a constructor either, it is a declaration of a function named `object` that has no parameters and returns an object of type `classname`.

Comment: @LucTouraille - yes about about the param list in the incorrect position. I pointed out the correction later.

Comment: @LucTouraille Regarding the other thing... the accidental function pointer declaration, you are absolutely right. I had never noticed that before. Will modify my answer. 
Didn't think I'd learn anything new from this question... but there ya go!

Comment: Hi guys, many thanks. Assigning params to classname was where I was going wrong, classname object(20, 20); is exactly what I needed. Thanks! I assume that this is because object is of the type classname, with object holding the data and not classname? I will look into members to define default data as this will be useful!

Comment: @ChrisJones Hey Chris. A class is an object definition. It can hold data and functions for manipulating that data. When you create an instance of an object it uses the class definition to define it's behavior, but each instance can have its own member data. I would recommend starting with some basic OOP books and an introductory C++ book. You'll progress far faster.